# How to pass ArrayList for another activity

Tags: android

I'm trying to pass an ArrayList to my new activity this way:

```
Intent it = new Intent(activity, DownloadSelectionActivity.class);
            it.putExtra("anos", yearList);
            activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, DownloadSelectionActivity.class));
```

my yearList is OK, I can see all values in Log, but when I try to get it using the code below, it returns a NullPointerExcepetion:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_downloadselection);

        ArrayList<Integer> anosLista = (ArrayList<Integer>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("anos");


        for (Integer anos : anosLista) {
            Log.d(Constants.DOWNLOAD_SELECTED_ACTIVITY, String.valueOf(anos));
        }
```

Exception:

```
03-25 20:11:18.144: E/AndroidRuntime(7899): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-25 20:11:18.144: E/AndroidRuntime(7899): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.facilit.target.app.android/br.com.facilit.target.app.android.DownloadSelectionActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-25 20:11:18.144: E/AndroidRuntime(7899):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
03-25 20:11:18.144: E/AndroidRuntime(7899):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
03-25 20:11:18.144: E/AndroidRuntime(7899):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-25 20:11:18.144: E/AndroidRuntime(7899):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
03-25 20:11:18.144: E/AndroidRuntime(7899):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-25 20:11:18.144: E/AndroidRuntime(7899):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-25 20:11:18.144: E/AndroidRuntime(7899):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-25 20:11:18.144: E/AndroidRuntime(7899):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-25 20:11:18.144: E/AndroidRuntime(7899):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-25 20:11:18.144: E/AndroidRuntime(7899):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-25 20:11:18.144: E/AndroidRuntime(7899):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-25 20:11:18.144: E/AndroidRuntime(7899):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-25 20:11:18.144: E/AndroidRuntime(7899): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-25 20:11:18.144: E/AndroidRuntime(7899):     at br.com.facilit.target.app.android.DownloadSelectionActivity.onCreate(DownloadSelectionActivity.java:26)
03-25 20:11:18.144: E/AndroidRuntime(7899):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
03-25 20:11:18.144: E/AndroidRuntime(7899):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
03-25 20:11:18.144: E/AndroidRuntime(7899):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
03-25 20:11:18.144: E/AndroidRuntime(7899):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
activity.startActivity(it);
```

instead of

```
activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, DownloadSelectionActivity.class));
```

for starting `DownloadSelectionActivity`. Currently you are not passing the Intent (`it`) with the ArrayList to start next Activity. Instead you are ignoring it by creating *another* Intent.

Comment: You might want to explain how your change works (i.e. that the OP is ignoring the first Intent created).

Comment: @Code-Guru : but i have already mention in my answer OP is not passing prepared intent(it) for starting next activity

Comment: Doh! I guess I should read the whole thing. You definitely have a very good answer here +1